# Degree symbol in short cut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-indesign

In Adobe InDesign one of the default keyboard shortcuts is described using a degree symbol. To which button of my keyboard is this symbol referencing? I don't have a degree sign on my keyboard.

[image: A snippet of a menu, where the short cut]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is `;` key. Show/hide guides. Lock/unlock gudies.

[image]